# How to sniff on virtual COM port in windows?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer the MediaTek flashing application for its smartphones. It works with a virtual COM port device as follows:

1. Device is attached, preloader exposes the COM port USB device for 1s and waits for some command by host
2. If no command comes in from the host, the USB device is deattached and normal boot resumes
3. If command comes in (the host software detects USB VID/PID and connects using windows comport api), then preloader accepts extended bootloader from PC and communicates over COM port

The problem is that due to the fact that the exposed COM port vanishes after one second I cannot use any conventional serial port monitoring software. Is there any way to sniff on the communication except sniffing and reimplementing the USB COM port protocol?

Comment: I need to do something similar, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a framework like FRIDA to hook the functions relating to the COM port and sniff it that way. Might be a bit of work though. http://www.frida.re

Comment: Ended up using Detours and hooking a dumpload of functions... tedious to write, I tell you.